# AS3 Bullet Removal

Tags: actionscript-3

everyone.

I'm trying to get my bullet instances to get deleted once they leave the screen, but I get this:

`Error 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method removeChild through a reference with static type __AS3__.vec:Vector.<Bullet>.`

This is where the error directs to:

```
private function manageBullets(event:Event):void {

    for each(var i in bManager.bulletVector){

        if (i.y < -20) {

            bManager.removeChild(i);     //This line
            bManager.bulletVector = bManager.bulletVector.splice(bManager.bulletVector.indexOf(i), 1);

        }
    }
}
```

I'm fairly new to AS3/OOP, so don't bash on me too hard :P

Comment: What is `bManager`? Where are you adding your bullets to? We need to see more code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing two incorrect things:

1) Trying to call removeChild() method on vector object. removeChild() child method is only accessible on DisplayObjectContainer and it's descendants classes.

2) You assign one of it's own elements to bulletVector which is returned by splice() so after this expression bulletVector is no longer vector instead it is bullet object. This should give you "TypeError" if bManager's class is not defined as dynamic.

I guess your code should look like this:

```
private function manageBullets(event:Event):void {

    for each(var i in bManager.bulletVector){

        if (i.y < -20) {

            if(i.parent != null) //Check if i is in display list
            {
                  i.parent.removeChild(i); //Remove i from display list
            }

            /* And then just remove i from vector no need to handle returned value.*/

            bManager.bulletVector.splice(bManager.bulletVector.indexOf(i), 1); 

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, but I've been told that you shouldn't use parent bar a few cases. Is this one of the exceptions?

Comment: I have used this practice in several my projects without problem, but anyways if you have one, then you should keep reference on parent/container DisplayObject and make check like: `if(parentDisplayObject.contains(i)) { parentDisplayObject.removeChild(i); }`